# Não funciona SQL

Tags: php, sql

Tenho esta função SQL numa codigo php mas não me esta a ir buscar os dados pedidos a base de dados

```
$query_part = "SELECT * 
FROM participacao 
WHERE manutencao = 'Equipamento' AND 'Material de saude' ORDER BY Id DESC";
```

Como devo escreve-la ou fazer?

Comment: Talvez deveria ser `manutencao = 'Equipamento' AND manutencao = 'Material de saude'` ou algo parecido... faltou informar o nome do campo

Comment: `Material de saude` seria o q?

Comment: material de saude é o que esta escrito dentro com campo manutencao

Answer (score 1):

É necessário informar o campo onde o **[where](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimization.html)** deve filtrar.

```
SELECT * 
FROM participacao 
WHERE manutencao = 'Equipamento'
AND NOME-DO-CAMPO = 'Material de saude' 
ORDER BY Id DESC
```

Caso você queira `manutencao = 'Equipamento' AND manutencao  = 'Material de saude'`, isso não é possível. Sempre vai retornar 0.

A depender dos dados que você queira retornar, você pode utilizar o seguinte:

```
SELECT * 
FROM participacao 
WHERE manutencao IN ('Equipamento', 'Material de saude') 
ORDER BY Id DESC
```

Comment: não funciona na mesma

Comment: Editei minha resposta. Verifica se é mais ou meno isso que você precisa.

Comment: Obrigado mas já resolvi, podes ate ver em cima como coloquei, mas obrigado a mesma

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer verificar se o valor é um ou outro, o correto é usar `OR`:

```
$query_part = "SELECT * 
FROM participacao 
WHERE manutencao = 'Equipamento' OR manutencao = 'Material de saude' ORDER BY Id DESC";
```

> Ao usar AND, você quer que o valor do campo seja obrigatoriamente os
>   dois valores informados na query. Com OR, você puxa se um valor igual a um ou outro, ou seja, todos os com "Equipamento" e todos os "Material de saude".

Comment: eu quero é mesmo o AND pois são 2 que quero mostrar

Comment: @AdelinoVasconcelos Pois eh Adelino. É impossível mostrar duas coisas de uma mesma coluna com dois valores diferentes usando AND.

Comment: então como devo fazer

Comment: @AdelinoVasconcelos Do jeito que respondi, usando OR, que vai pegar uma coisa ou outra.

Comment: eu eu pretendo as 2 coisas porque ao todo tem 3 que eu pretendo 2

Comment: @AdelinoVasconcelos Então, se o valor for ''Equipamento" ou "Material de saude", vai retornar tudo que tiver um desses dois valores.

Comment: mas ainda tem outro valor Oficina

Comment: @AdelinoVasconcelos O "Oficina" não vai entrar.

Comment: correcto,eu pretendo que apareça somente os outros dois

Comment: @AdelinoVasconcelos Pode usar o OR normalmente, dizendo o que vc quer que retorne.

Comment: @AdelinoVasconcelos Quando vc coloca AND, vc está dizendo que tem que ser OS DOIS VALORES ao mesmo tempo, e não um ou outro.

Comment: já consegui mas obrigado a todos na mesma

Comment: @AdelinoVasconcelos Que bom. Marque a resposta com ✓. Isso ajudará pessoas no futuro que tiverem o mesmo problema. Abs!

Comment: so daqui a 2 dias

Comment: @AdelinoVasconcelos Uai, por que?

Answer (score 0):

Para quem tenha a mesma duvida que eu aqui fica uma Dica

```
$query_part = "SELECT * FROM participacao WHERE NOT manutencao = 'Oficina' ORDER BY Id DESC";
```